# (TypeScript) How to capture the type provided by the user inside the generic function?

Tags: generics, typescript, generic-programming

I am new to TypeScript and this is the function I've written:

```
/**
     * @function getComponent()
     * @description finds and returns the requested type of component, null if not found
     * @return {any} component
     */
    public getComponent<T extends Component>(): T{
        for(let i = 0; i < this.componentList.length; i++){
            if(<T>this.componentList[i] instanceof Component){
                return this.componentList[i] as T;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This function is inside the GameObject class which contains a list of Component objects

Component is an abstract function that can be extended by other classes. I want this function to return the type of Component requested by the user. For example something like this:

```
let gameObject = new GameObject();
let audioComponent = gameObject.getComponent<AudioComponent>(); // no syntax error because AudioComponent extends Component
let myComponent = gameObject.getComponent<foo>(); // syntax error, foo doesn't extend Component
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know the generic type at runtime, all of the types are being removed by the compiler because it's not supported in javascript.

If I understand you, then maybe this can do the trick for you:

```
abstract class Component {}

class Component1 extends Component {}
class Component2 extends Component {}
class Component3 extends Component {}

class ComponentsArray extends Array<Component> {
    public getInstanceFor<T extends Component>(componentClass: { new (): T }) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            if ((<any> this[i].constructor).name === (<any> componentClass).name) {
                return this[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

let array = new ComponentsArray();
array.push(new Component1());
array.push(new Component2());
array.push(new Component3());

let component2: Component2 = array.getInstanceFor(Component2);
console.log(component2); // Component2 {}
```

If you'll replace the `componentList` member you have in your `GameObject` class from (what I assume is) a regular `Array` to `ComponentsArray` then your `getComponent` function is simple:

```
public getComponent<T extends Component>(componentClass: { new (): T }): T {
    return this.componentList.getInstanceFor(componentClass);
}
```

And then:

```
let gameObject = new GameObject();
let audioComponent = gameObject.getComponent(AudioComponent);
```